# How to get attributes of the current instance of the class in Django CBV

Tags: django, django-views

I'm building a tagging system for my blog using [django-taggit](https://django-taggit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#) module. I would like to get a list of all tags that the current post has when I open this post with a DetailView. Seems easy, but I just can't figure it out.

I thought I would override the default `get_queryset` method in the DetailView class like this:

```
def get_queryset(self):
  post_tags_ids = Post.tags.values_list('id', flat=True)
```

but if later I:

```
print(post_tags_ids)
```

I get:

```
<QuerySet [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]>
```

which is a queryset for **all** tags I have so far for all posts.

I thought Django was smart enough to know to reference the current instance and I'm sure it is, so how do I get the attributes of the current instance of the class in Django

Answer (score 1):

First of all you should use your post object to get all related tags not the whole Post class.
Suppose you have a field like `tags = TaggableManager(verbose_name=_('tags'), related_name='posts')` in your Post model (note that there is a related_name as posts), then you should use that related name to get related objects (or model default related manager).
In your DetailView you can use the method `get_object()` to get the current post object. After that you can use this method in your get_context_data or in other places and use some arbitrary key to add it to your context. For more information check the following code:

```
class PostDetailView(DetailView):
    queryset = Post.objects.all()
    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        post_obj = self.get_object()
        context = super().get_context_data()
        context['related_tags'] = post_obj.posts.all() # or post_obj.posts.values_list('id', flat=True)
        return context
```

Which `posts` is your related name in your Post field. Finally in your template you can use `related_tags` as your Post related tags which is the current post object related tags.

Comment: Thank you for the help. If I use `_('tags')` then the interpreter complains about undefined variable of `_`. So I had to remove it as well as parenthesis, since they were not required. Also `post_obj.posts.all()` was raising an error, since the interpreter complained that the `post_obj` had no attribute `posts`. But when I replaced `posts` with `tags` it worked just fine. So I think the problem was solved by setting the verbose name and then referring to it. Although I *think* I could refer to the tags without using the verbose name but using `tags_set` instead (AFAIR)

Comment: You're welcome, and yes I just made a little mistake in related name (posts instead of tags).